# Check a list of DTOs using linq to see if all values that exclude a particular value all equal the same thing

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of DTOs filled with values. I want to check to see if a certain value across all the DTOs is the same while excluding a specific value. In other words I need to take a subset of this list and then check if all values are equal.

I initially tried

```
itemList.Where(x => x.status != 17).All(x => x.status == 15)
```

but it is evaluating true when all DTOs in the list have status = 17. I wanted to get a subset of DTOs that didn't have status 17 and then check if all of those DTOs have a status of 15. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: "but it is evaluating true when all DTOs in the list have status = 17"  All remaining zero values pass your other test, so why wouldn't it return true?

Comment: Just check that the count of all with status !=17 is equal to the count of all where status ==15. `itemList.Count(x => x.Status != 17) == itemList.Count(x => x.Status ==15)`

Comment: @slugster - that gives him the same result he's complaining about.  Apparently we want to make sure at least 1 record exists with the desired value (15)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there might be some confusion about what to do with empty collections in this question.  I find that partitioning the source into sub-collections can lend clarity to any decisions.

```
var lookup = itemsList.ToLookup(x =>
  x.Status == 17 ? "Exclude" :
  x.Status == 15 ? "Include" :
  "Trouble");

bool hasTrouble = lookup["Trouble"].Any();
bool hasInclude = lookup["Include"].Any();
bool hasOnlyGoodOnes = !hasTrouble && hasInclude;
var goodOnes = lookup["Include"].ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah the issue turned out to be that I just didn't realize that .All always returns true on empty lists. So I ended up more or less doing what you did. I partitioned off the DTOs without status 17, used .Any() to see whether it was empty, and then used .All if if that returned true.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your requirements are:

1. Ignore anything where Status = 17
2. Of the remaining records, ensure that they all have a status of 15
3. Ensure there is at least one record

I believe that can be accomplished with

```
bool ok = itemList
    .Select( x => x.Status )   //Just look at statuses
    .Where( x => x != 17)      //Ignore 17
    .Distinct()                //Collapse to one element per status
    .SingleOrDefault()         //Make sure there is only one element
    == 15;                     //Make sure the status is 15
```

Answer (score 1):

`.All` checks if there are no elements that *cannot satisfy* the condition. So it returns `true` for empty sets.

If I understood your intent right, you can instead try

```
itemsList.Count(i => i.status != 17 && i.status != 15) > 0;
```

I.e. simply filter out all the 17s and 15s, and see if there's anything else left.

Comment: I like it, but it has the same issue as the .All approach: the presence or absence of 15's does not change the outcome.